# Dynamic inputs from a Behavior in reactive-banana

Tags: haskell, reactive-banana

When I want to work with dynamic inputs in reactive-banana, I usually envision a system that works roughly like this:

```
data InputSpecification -- Some data structure that specifies the inputs
                        -- which should be active right now

data MyInterestingData -- Some data that is relevant to my business logic
                       -- and is gathered through the dynamic inputs.

emptyData :: MyInterestingData
emptyData = -- Some initial MyInterestingData

setupDynamicInputs :: Event (InputSpecification) -> MomentIO (Behavior MyInterestingData)
setupDynamicInputs specE = do
    newBehavior <- execute $ updateDynamicInputs <$> specE
    switchB emptyData newBehavior

updateDynamicInputs :: InputSpecification -> MomentIO (Behavior MyInterestingData)
updateDynamicInputs = -- Here the dynamic inputs are set up according to
                      -- the specification and set up to update the returned
                      -- Behavior
```

This works quite nicely and the inputs are updated whenever a new `InputSpecification` is fired.

A problem I often stumble across is that my `InputSpecification` doesn't come in an `Event` but rather as a `Behavior InputSpecification` (probably because I needed `Applicative` combinators to construct it). The above approach doesn't work then, as `execute` and `switchB` can't be used on `Behaviors`.

As a simple solution, I could use this function from the [reactive-banana documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-1.1.0.1/docs/Reactive-Banana-Frameworks.html):

> ```
> plainChanges :: Behavior a -> MomentIO (Event a)
> plainChanges b = do
>     (e, handle) <- newEvent
>     eb <- changes b
>     reactimate' $ (fmap handle) <$> eb
>     return e
> ```

Then I could just use `setupDynamicInputs` on the `Event` obtained from `plainChanges`, but:

> However, this approach is not recommended[...]

So I'm a bit reluctant to use this approach.

Is there a "cleaner" approach to keep my inputs in sync with the specification, when the specification is kept in a `Behavior`?

## Edit

As Heinrich Apfelmus pointed out in his answer, the solution to my original question is not to use a `Behavior` for updating the `InputSpecification`. While I can understand the reasoning behind that, it doesn't solve the problem I'm having, so I will try to explain why I wanted to use a `Behavior` here.

Updating the input through an `Event` is easy as long as the input is specified by a single input. As an example, if the dynamic inputs consists of a sequence of inputs, the specification for those inputs would just be an non-negative integer that denotes how many inputs should be shown.

It gets more complex once the input specification is obtained via more than one input. For example, let's say our `InputSpecification` becomes `(Word, Word)` and specifies a grid of input with the given dimensions. If I obtain those dimensions via two different inputs, I would have to combine two `Event Word`s into one `Event (Word, Word)`, which isn't really a trivial task for `Event`s as they don't have an `Applicative` instance like `Behavior`s do. That's why I usually like to use `Behavior`s in such cases, but as discussed before they don't get you further when you actually want to create the inputs. So if `Behavior`s aren't the right solution here and `Event`s tend to get tediously hard (or impossible in the worst cases) to combine, what is the right solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, one reason why this may not work is that it, perhaps, should not work. There is a litmus test for determining whether modeling the situation with a `Behavior` makes sense: What happens if `Behavior InputSpecification` were a genuinely *continuous* function? Say, you had a continuous frequency range (e.g. for radio stations) and each frequency would be associated to a new input that has to be set up. If you were to do a continuous frequency sweep, then you would have to create and discard infinitely many inputs, which is not possible. This is an indication that there is a deeper reason behind `Event InputSpecification` being the right type.

More generally, the `Behavior` type encapsulates two important invariants:

1. It does not depend on a sample rate.
2. You cannot detect when or how often it "changes". For instance, if you have an `Event` whose occurrences all have the same value `[(0 seconds, x), (2 seconds, x), ..]`, then this invariant says that applying `stepper` to this will yield a `Behavior` that is *indistinguishable* from `pure x`.

For pragmatic reasons, invariant 2 can be circumvented with `changes` function. You are allowed to use it if you feel that it "morally preserves the invariant". For instance, you can use it to display a text value on the screen only when the Behavior changes; this is more efficient than, say, polling at a fixed sample rate. Since the visual end result is the same for either Behavior mentioned above, you morally preserve the invariant in this case.

---

EDIT:

It looks like you need more explicit control about when to update. In this case, you can use an explicit event `e :: Event ()` that keeps track of when the inputs should be updated. Then, you can use the following combination to update the inputs only when this event triggers

```
e2 <- plainChanges (imposeChanges b e)
execute $ updateDynamicInputs <$> e2
...
```

(There should be a pure alternative for this, I will look into this.)

Alternatively, you can replicate a "Behavior with notification for updates" machinery by hand, for instance introducing a type

```
data Dynamic a = D (Behavior a) (Event a)
```

and implement `Applicative` etc instances for this. This is a bit heavyweight but may be just what you need.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It doesn't help me solve the actual my problem though, so I edited my answer to clarify what that actually is.

Comment: Oh, I see, I like the new example. However, it also shows that discussing the semantics of `Behavior` is important. For instance, I imagine that the the dimensions of the grid are taken from two slider widgets. What happens if the user grabs the slider, moves it a bit, but not enough to change its value. Question: Will all the inputs in the grid be created anew, so that any values that the user has put in before be *lost*?

Comment: I think you meant to use `plainChanges` in your first example, otherwise I don't see how it typechecks.

Comment: Normally I aim to re-use previously created inputs, so their current values aren't lost. However, this only works with `accumE` or `accumB`, which need `Event`s as input. I think the examples you have given in your edit solve this quite nicely. A combinator `executeLater :: Event (Future (MomentIO a)) -> Event a` would be handy for working with `changes` without resorting to `plainChanges`.